# Golang consume json with dynamic relevant keys

Tags: json, go, dynamic, unmarshalling

I am new to GO and I am trying to consume json data from a variety of API's using GO and place them in struct's one of them Formats the data like so

```
{"MS": {
   "last":"25",
"highestBid":"20"},
"GE": {        
    "last": "24",        
    "highestBid": "22"}
}
```

While I can find information on Consuming with dynamic keys, all the examples I found throw away the Outer most key as arbitrary and irrelevant. I need to use it as a key value pair like bellow:

```
{"MarketName": "GE", "last":"24","higestBid":"22"}
```

I understand Using Interface map but I cant figure out how to map the dynamic key to the struct as a key : value pair like above.  My Code example to map leaving out the need key can be found at play ground [Relevant Code](https://play.golang.org/p/GP-8yD0knku)

```
  package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

)

var jsonBytes = []byte(`
    {"MS": {
       "last":"25",
    "highestBid":"20"},
    "GE": {        
        "last": "24",        
        "highestBid": "22"}
    }`)

type Market struct {
    Last       string 
    HighestBid string 
}

func main() {
    // Unmarshal using a generic interface
    var f interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBytes, &f)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error parsing JSON: ", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(f)



}
```

as it stands it outputs

```
map[MS:map[last:25 highestBid:20] GE:map[highestBid:22 last:24]]
```

As I stated I am new to GO and as much help and explanation that i can get would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're halfway there already, you just need to unmarshal into your struct and then massage the data a little:

```
type Market struct {
    Name string
    Last       string 
    HighestBid string 
}

func main() {
    // Unmarshal using a generic interface
    var f map[string]Market
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBytes, &f)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error parsing JSON: ", err)
        return
    }
    markets := make([]Market, 0, len(f))
    for k,v := range f {
        v.Name = k
        markets = append(markets,v)
    }
    fmt.Println(markets)
}
```

Working example here: https://play.golang.org/p/iagx8RWFfx_k

Comment: Thank you so much, as expected someone better could make it look so easy!

Answer (score 0):

If a slice of Markets is a data structure that's going to be useful to you, you might wish to alias it and implement `MarketList.UnmarshalJSON([]byte)`, like so:

```
type Market struct {
    MarketName string
    Last       string
    HighestBid string
}

type MarketList []Market

func (ml *MarketList) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    tmp := map[string]Market{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &tmp)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var l MarketList
    for k, v := range tmp {
        v.MarketName = k
        l = append(l, v)
    }

    *ml = l
    return nil
}

func main() {
    ml := MarketList{}
    // Unmarshal directly into a []Market alias
    _ = json.Unmarshal(jsonBytes, &ml)

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", ml)
}
```

[Runnable version here](https://play.golang.org/p/7s79Nzybzfn).